# calling methods on .net object from coldfusion

Tags: c#, .net, coldfusion, language-interoperability

I am trying to instantiate and call methods on a .net object created from a dll from coldfusion.  This works when I call methods with one or zero arguments but fails with -

> System.MissingMethodException: Could not find the generic method coldfusion2net.test.setvars

when I try to call a method with more than one arg.

Here is my simple C# class:

```
namespace coldfusion2net
{
    public class test
    {
        protected string myvar;
        protected string myvar2;
        public void setvars(string v, string v2) {
            myvar = v;
            myvar2 = v2;
        }
        public void setvar(string v) {
            myvar = v;
        }
        public string getvar(){
            return myvar;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my ColdFusion test:

```
<cfset dll = ExpandPath('./coldfusion2net.dll')>
<cfobject type=".NET" name="test" class="coldfusion2net.test" assembly="#dll#">
<cfset test.init()>
<!--- object has been loaded --->
<cfdump var="#test#">
<!--- so far so good --->
<cfset test.setvar("foo")>
<cfset s = test.getvar()>
<cfoutput>#s#</cfoutput>
<!--- wtf??? --->
<cfset test.setvars("foo","bar")>
```

To compile the dll, I am using visual studio 2010 targeting the .net 3.5 runtime (which is what we have on our servers).  I am using ColdFusion     **8,0,0,176276**    to try and load the dll.

Has anyone else seen anything like this?  Am I doing something wrong?  Is this a CF bug?

I looked in the article on the Adobe live docs on .NET Interoperability Limitations but the closest thing I found is "ColdFusion cannot determine the correct data type conversion if a method has multiple signatures that have the same number of parameters and differ only in the parameter data types".  This does not seem to be the problem here.

Comment: CFdump the `#test#` object. Do you see the setVars() method?

Comment: have you tried `javacast("string","foo")` ?

Comment: @Leigh when I dump the object I see all the methods.  The method in question says - setvars(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: @Henry tried the javacast, got the same error

Comment: hmm... maybe you can make that .dll available for us to test in CF9.0.1?

Comment: @Nick - Maybe a bug/compatibility issue? Seemed to work okay for me with 9,0,1,274733 and VS2005. Let me test it with 8.0.1

Comment: I put up the zipped dll here - http://www.physle.com/public/

Comment: edited - I just looked and apparently our dev server was never updated to 8.0.1 the version in use is correct now.

Comment: @Nick - Sorry, no luck finding a CF8 test box right now. But your dll does work under CF9. So maybe it is an issue that was fixed .. ?

Comment: @Henry - My take was he was just correcting a typo. But that it still did not work. So @Nick .. is it fixed or still broken? ;)

Comment: I just updated the server info in the question.  It's not fixed.  I think we have a test server with 9 on it.  I will give it a shot there

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps, but...

> upgrading the .NET version to 3.5
>   caused the problem, since the
>   ColdFusion .NET integration service
>   had configured itself to use the
>   earlier version of the .NET framework.
>   Uninstalling and then reinstalling
>   ColdFusion .NET integration service
>   fixed the problem in my case.

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/25391?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up here.  Moving to CF9 fixed this.   I never did figure out how to get it working under 8.